# Azure SQL Import Data-tier is not successful

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to import Azure SQL database to my local environment, I am facing the Create Database Scoped Credential issue while importing it. What is the possible solution for this? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I belive scoped credentials are supported in S**QL Server 2016** so you either try it with that or you remove the credentials before importing it:

[DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current)

Answer (score 1):

Please consider dropping the database scoped credential as shown below:

```
DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL CredentialName
```

If that scoped credential was created to create external data sources, then you will have to drop them first.

```
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE SourceName
```